# Why can't I use `user.roles = {...}` to add to a json string?

Tags: node.js, json

I have the following model prototype (using Sequelize):

```
User.prototype.getUserWithRoles = async function () {
    let user = this;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
    // prints {"id":288,"username":"test", ...}

    user.roles = {"Traveler": true};  //just for testing, I've set this as a static value
    console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
    // prints {"id":288,"username":"test", ...}

    ...
```

For the last line, I would have expected different output. I would have expected:

```
{
  "id":288,
  "username":"test", 
   ...,
   "roles": {
       "Traveler": true
   }
}
```

But the `roles` part is missing. What could be the cause of this?
Is the format `user.roles = {...}` not valid?

Comment: I think you want to use a [virtual field](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/getters-setters-virtuals/#virtual-fields). Documents returned by queries aren't regular objects. Also, instead of adding methods to its prototype, you should probably use [proper inheritance](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#taking-advantage-of-models-being-classes).

Comment: But I don't really need a virtual field for this, do I? I mean I have a json string and just want to expand that json string a bit before I return it. Perhaps it can be done with a virtual field, but I think it should also be possible directly inside the prototype? Also, I don't understand why what I do isn't working (it was working when I was still using Knex as ORM instead of Sequelize).

Comment: `user` isn't a JSON string (or a regular Object), it's a Model instance, which are two very different things. Sequelize isn't Knex and works differently. The way to do this with Sequelize is through virtuals (or _possibly_ in another way, but you're not explaining what exactly it is you're trying to achieve other than adding a property to an object; do you want to be able to save the document later on? Do you want to convert the Model instance to a regular Object?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queries in Sequelize don't return regular objects, but Model instance, to which you can't just add properties (well, you obviously *can*, but they won't show up when you stringify the object).

Instead, you have to define a [virtual field](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/getters-setters-virtuals/#virtual-fields), which are fields that look like they are a part of the Model instance, but won't actually be saved to the database:

```
roles: {
  type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
  get() {
    return { Traveler : true };
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if your goal is to return a regular object of a Model instance with a `roles` property added to it, you could use something like this (using [Model inheritance](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#extending-model)):

```
class User extends Model {
  getUserWithRoles() {
    const obj = this.toJSON(); // convert to a regular Javascript object
    obj.roles = { Traveler : true };
    return obj;
  }
}
```